Magento 2 : Create Customer Not Working After Upgrade to 2.4.6
We upgraded from 2.4.2 to 2.4.6-P4. Now create customer account is not working anymore. When the form is filled and the button 'create account' is clicked only the form reloads. The customer is not added to the database.
Can anyone please help how to fix it?


Looks at error logs
Look at console log error
--> spontaneously, my thoughts are to looks at csp or cors. For the former, it is the most obvious as csp has changed recently. For cors, it seems to have become a problem more common than it was before but again, I'd focus on csp much more than cors


CSP is not the problem.
When I try to add a customer manually it gives also an error: Attribute is_approved does not contain option with Id new

If you are using custom theme please change to Magento_luma may be there are some hidden field/input. like store frontend Captcha.

Thank you for your help, but in luma all the problems are still there.
